# A nonexistent object was used in an `Input` of a Dash callback an multipage app

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to build a basic webpage in Dash and Plotly, using callbacks to deliver stock graphs based on the pathname.

I would also like the graph to have a callback with radio buttons that specify the time period of data to display.

The graphs work fine however I would also like other pages to do other things and return different html but because I have specified the callback_layout in the @app.layout, it shows up on every page.

However, If I remove the callback_layout from @app.layout, I get an error in Dash saying "A nonexistent object was used in an `Input` of a Dash callback an multipage app".

How would I solve this? I want the callback radio buttons under 'stock-period' to only show up when I need to pull up the Plotly graph

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.CYBORG] #DARKLY

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)


# styling the sidebar
SIDEBAR_STYLE = {
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": 0,
    "left": 0,
    "bottom": 0,
    "width": "16rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",
    # "background-color": "#4C4C4C",
}

# padding for the page content
CONTENT_STYLE = {
    "margin-left": "18rem",
    "margin-right": "2rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",
    "background-color": "#060606"
}

sidebar = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("Sidebard / Stocks", className="display-4"),
        html.Hr(),
        html.P(
            "Number of students per education level", className="lead"
        ),
        dbc.Nav(
            [
                dbc.NavLink("Home", href="/", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("Test", href="/test", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("NVDA", href="/NVDA", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("MSFT", href="/MSFT", active="exact"),
                dbc.NavLink("AAPL", href="/AAPL", active="exact"),
            ],
            vertical=True,
            pills=True,
        ),
    ],
    style=SIDEBAR_STYLE,
)



content = html.Div(id="page-content", children=[], style=CONTENT_STYLE)  # Graph goes inside children via call back 

callback_layout = html.Div([   
                dcc.RadioItems(
                    id='period-selector',
                    options = [
                        {'label': '1 mth', 'value': '1mo'},
                        {'label': '3 mth', 'value': '3mo'},
                        {'label': '6 mth', 'value': '6mo'},
                        {'label': '1 yr', 'value': '1y'},
                        {'label': '5 yr', 'value': '5y'}
                    ],
                    value = "6mo",

                    #labelStyle is done in CSS 
                    labelStyle={
                        'textAlign': 'center',
                        'display': 'inline-block', 
                        'color': 'white',
                        'font-family': 'Arial',
                        'font-size' : '15px',
                        'padding-right': '30px'
                    },

                    style={
                        'textAlign': 'center'
                    }
                )
                ])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
    sidebar,
    content,
    callback_layout
])


homepage_layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 1', href='/page-1'),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Link('Go to Page 2', href='/page-2'),
])

""" Plotly graph """
@app.callback(
    Output("page-content", "children"),
    Input("url", "pathname"),
    Input('period-selector', 'value')
)

def render_page_content(pathname, period_selector):
    """ App routing from sidebar to content depending on path """
    if pathname == '/':
        return homepage_layout
    
    if pathname == '/test':
        return 'Test'
    
    else:  # If pathname isn't defined above, assume is stock ticker and calls graph below 
        interval = '1d'

        quote = yf.Ticker(pathname)
        hist = quote.history(period_selector, interval)
        df = hist.round(decimals=2)
        
        last_price = df.iloc[-1, 0] # return first row (-1)

        #Performance over period calc
        performance_calc = ((df.iloc[-1, 0] / df.iloc[0, 0]) - 1) * 100
        if performance_calc >= 0:
            performance = '+' + str(round(performance_calc,2))
        else:
            performance = str(round(performance_calc,2))
        
        #Define color of performance % 
        performance_int = (round(performance_calc,2))
        
        if performance_int >= 0:
            perf_color = 'lime'
        else:
            perf_color = 'red'
        
        fig = px.line(df, 
            x=df.index, y=df["Close"], 
            title='NVDA',
            template="plotly_dark",
            color_discrete_sequence=['lime'],
            labels = {'Date': ''}
            )
        
        if interval == '1mo':
            d_tick='604800000'  #7 days in milliseconds. Datetime format requires ms input. 
        elif interval == '5y':
            d_tick = 'M12'
        else:
            d_tick='M1'

        fig.update_xaxes(
            dtick=d_tick,
            showgrid=False,            
        )

        fig.update_yaxes(
            showgrid=False,
            visible=False
        )
        #Last price annotation 
        fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color='white',size=40, family='Arial Black'),
            x=0,
            y=1.2,
            showarrow=False,
            text=str(last_price),
            textangle=0,
            xanchor='left',
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper")
        )

        #Performance annotation 
        fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color=perf_color,size=25, family='Arial'),
            x=0.14,
            y=1.12,
            showarrow=False,
            text=str(performance) + '%',
            textangle=0,
            xanchor='left',
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper")
        )

        fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None)
        
        fig.update_layout(
            plot_bgcolor='#060606',
            paper_bgcolor='#060606',
            font_color='white',
            title=dict(   
                y = 0.82,  #Adjust location of stock ticker title 
                x = 0.92,
                xanchor = 'center',
                yanchor = 'top',
                font=dict(
                    family="Arial",
                    size=25,
                    color='white'
                    )
            ),
            hovermode = 'x',
            # xaxis_tickformat = '%b'
        )

        # Return below into children tag above 
        return [
                html.H1(pathname,
                        style={'textAlign':'center'}),
                dcc.Graph(id='stock-chart',
                    figure = fig
                    )
                ]

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=3000)
```

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but I would highly recommend you use different python files for each page, import, and then use them on a callback in the main file that handles the URL changes (a router). There will come a time when the amount of logic will be too big to leave on only one file. Those are just my two cents though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired behavior you can just hide the chart radio buttons for all endpoints that do not build the stock price graph.  To do this add the style attribute of the period-selector element as an output to your main callback as shown below.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
    sidebar,
    content,
    callback_layout # Leave this here, do not move.
])

@app.callback(
    Output("page-content", "children"),
    Output("period-selector", "style"),  # Add new output here
    Input("url", "pathname"),
    Input('period-selector', 'value')
)
def render_page_content(pathname, period_selector):
    """ App routing from sidebar to content depending on path """
    hidden_style = {'display': 'none'}
    #  It would be best to make visible_style a module level variable.
    #  Use it for both the app layout and this callback function.
    #  That way if you want to change its location or look you only have to edit one location.
    visible_style = {'textAlign': 'center'} 
    if pathname == '/':
        return homepage_layout, hidden_style

    if pathname == '/test':
        return 'Test', hidden_style
    
    else:
        # Your other build code here.
        return [
            html.H1(pathname,
                    style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
            dcc.Graph(id='stock-chart',
                      figure=fig
                      )
        ], visible_style
```

Comment: Great to hear.  Please mark this as the answer so that your question is shown as answered in the system. My final departing advice is make the layout of each of your pages a separate function instead of putting the HTML code for 3 different layouts in the same callback.  Try to break your functionality out into multiple callback functions that each accomplish one or two small things.  Giant callbacks are a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiplexerTransform` from [`dash-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/dash-extensions/) was designed to solve this problem. To enable it, replace you imports from `Dash` with their equivalents from `dash-extensions.enrich`,

```
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, html, ...  # before
from dash_extensions.enrich import Dash, Input, Output, html, ...  # after
```

and the error should disappear. You can read more about the details in the [documentation](https://www.dash-extensions.com/transforms/multiplexer-transform).